# How can I create a jQuery object from innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which holds the innerHtml of an object (received via a call to `$.html()`).

How can I create a jQuery object based on that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(htmlString)
```

This will hold all of the elements in the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the original jQuery object you called the `.html()` on, you can access its children directly by using the `.children()` method:

```
var $children = $obj.children();
```

This will return them as jQuery array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newelement= $('<div/>');
newelement.html(htmlString);
```

This differs slightly from SLaks's answer in that it preserves direct text node children.  jQuery's `$(htmlString)` construction shortcut, like many of its features, only deals with Element nodes and not Text nodes.

So if `htmlString` is `'foo<bar>bof</bar>zot'`, and you wanted to keep the `foo` and the `zot`, you'd have to do it this way.

Similarly with Xion's answer, if you wanted to keep direct text node children, you'd have to use the more-unusual `contents()` method rather than `children()`.